# Why is Laravel 5.5 Session data lost after loggin out?

Tags: php, laravel, session, logout

I understand that laravel will generate a new session id when a user logs in, but in that case it retains the session data, but why does the data go away when the user logs out? So here is a method I am calling to get the CartID from the session:

```
public function getId()
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        if (!session()->has('CartID'))
            session()->put('CartID', session()->getId());
        return session('CartID');
    }
    else {
        return session('CartID', '');
    }
}
```

I pass the CartID from the above method and also the current session ID to a blade and display them. (this is just for devlopment purposes to "test" how this works.)
So when I first go to website and I am NOT logged in it displays the same value for Cart ID and Session ID as one would expect. Then I login and go back to that page and then it displays the original (same) Cart ID but a new Session ID, which is also what one would expect. I have even tested completely closing my browser and reopening and when I go back I still have the original Cart ID with a different session ID (same as when it was closed). So this proves the session data is still intact after closing the browser. So far so good. However if I logout then go to the page the CartID has now changed to the new session ID, so I lost the original value of the Cart ID. This shows that when I logout I am losing all of my session data.
Below is what I think might be useful from my session config file:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'lifetime' => 2880,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'encrypt' => true,
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

Can anyone explain why the session data is lost after logging out?
I am running php 7.1 and Laravel 5.5
Thanks in advance

Comment: i think laravel refresh session after logout, can you check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the session is invalidated: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9a912d6f7da4d15144d73afc9213a5ef0f8db3e2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L157

Comment: Well technically that does answer my question.... Wish I would have rephrased the question to ask is there a way to save / restore the session while logging out? I think would probably be what most people would want to know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the user's session data (which inherently, it wasn't designed that way), you should make a database table and store the data that way. Or consider using cookies.

In short, the session data is supposed to be cleared after logging out.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my Cart facade for AvoRed E Commerce. I am not having an any issue.
If you want to give it a try AvoRed feel free but its under development now.

https://github.com/avored/framework/blob/master/src/Cart/Manager.php